# Running docker in docker in plain k3s installation?

Tags: k3s

I might have a really stupid/totally obvious answer question for you, but struggling with it: I try to use docker in docker (dind) on a k3s cluster (running rhel8) as a container in a pod. k3s has been installed with the shell script `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -`. Docker is not installed, nor podman is.

```
k3s -v
k3s version v1.25.4+k3s1 (0dc63334)
go version go1.19.3
```

```
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8 (Ootpa)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-477.13.1.el8_8.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Thanks for taking your time

I tried to expose `/run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock` to the dind container instead of `/var/run/docker.sock` on docker installed machine. But I don't know where to get the certs for the tls connection to containerd.